# Heroku with plone and mr.developer

Tags: python, heroku, plone, buildout

I am trying to deploy a plone on heroku, but I got some unreleased packages. I then use mr.developer to develop them with the buildout.

I use this buildpack https://github.com/plone/heroku-buildpack-plone then my buildout is well launched on heroku, but I got an error when mr.developer is trying to checkout my package.

Did I miss something? Or is there an alternative to deploy unreleased package with buildout?

Here is the error:

```
-----> Run bin/buildout -c heroku.cfg
Getting distribution for 'mr.developer==1.31'.
Got mr.developer 1.31.
mr.developer: Creating missing sources dir /tmp/build_c5c2025ff75d0cb4931f9747e9290849/devel.
mr.developer: Queued 'ipplf.core' for checkout.
mr.developer: Cloned 'ipplf.core' with git.
mr.developer: git submodule init failed.
mr.developer:
mr.developer: There have been errors, see messages above.

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Plone app
```

Here is what the important lines in my buildout.cfg looks like:

```
[buildout]
extensions = mr.developer

auto-checkout =
  ipplf.core

[sources]
ipplf.core = git git://github.com/affinitic/ipplf.core.git
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't get a specific answer to your question, why don't you simply make a release on github, host your development egg there and add it to your `find-link` buildout section?

Comment: Well I don't want to loose flexibility of developed packages. But if I don't find a solution to that specific problem, I guess that's what I'll do.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good opposition.

Answer (score 0):

According to mr.developer: **git submodule init failed**. Since [heroku supports submodules](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules#git-submodules) , you probably need to fix yours; possibly by "embed(ding) the username and password into the repository URL":

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules#protected-git-submodules

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, simply put the 'http' version of the source works.

Then:

```
[sources]
ipplf.core = git http://github.com/schminitz/ipplf.core.git
```

Comment: Nice, so we can use heroku also in full developer mode